# How to change methor free shipping follow price product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try custom flat rate in plugin woocommerce wordpress, defauld flat rate any class 45$, but i want products have price from 11$ will free shipping.
please help me!

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'diy_free_delivery');
 function diy_free_delivery($rates, $package){
    $product = new WC_Product();
    $price = $product->regular_price;
    if($price > 11){
        unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );

        $free_shipping = $rates['free_shipping'];
        $rates         = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
    }
    return $rates;
 }
```

Comment: Shipping is typically calculated for the cart total - you want to give free shipping if the customer has a product that is more than $11 will be free, otherwise charge them $45 for shipping?

Comment: i want to give free shipping if the customer has a product that is more than $11 will be free, and not use $45 for shipping

Comment: So if the total value of the items in the cart is greater than $11, they get free shipping? Doesn't matter if there is 1 product that is $12 or 2 products that are $6 each?

Comment: because i allow buy only 1 product for 1 times so i ignore  the upper case

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`woocommerce_package_rates`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shipping.html#366) filter to determine which shipping options are available depending on the value of your cart. The filter will pass in the `$available_methods` that you can modify within your function based on the value of the cart using [`WC()->get_cart_subtotal()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#_get_cart_subtotal).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'diy_free_delivery' );
function diy_free_delivery( $available_methods ){
    // check to see if the cart total is more than $11
    if ( WC()->get_cart_subtotal() > 11 ){
        // if it is we *only* want to show the free shipping
        return array( 'free_shipping' => $available_methods['free_shipping'] );
    } else {
        // if not we want to remove free_shipping and return the other methods
        unset( $available_methods['free_shipping'] );
        return $available_methods;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, try using the updated answer example - `return array( 'free_shipping' => $available_methods['free_shipping'] );`